# Echoing JSON array in PHP

Tags: php, json

After trying for a long period of time I am a bit stuck... I want to echo a value (url) in a json array with PHP and get it into a variable.

PHP:

```
$coverphotos = $facebook->api('http://graph.facebook.com/' . $album['id'] . '/picture?type=album&redirect=false&access_token=' . $access_token);
```

JSON:

```
{
"data": {
  "url": "http://photos-c.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/480080_567808343263483_176928672_a.jpg"
}
}
```

I want to get the actual url into a php variable... how would I go about doing this?

HOLY THAT TOOK LONG ENOUGH BUT I FIGURED IT OUT:

```
$coverphotos2 = $coverphotos['id'] . '?type=album&redirect=false&access_token=' . $access_token;

        $content = file_get_contents($coverphotos2); 
        $photoarray = json_decode($content, TRUE); 
        $coverurl = $photoarray['data']['url'];
```

Comment: Have a look at json_decode

Comment: Can you elaborate what specifically you tried in that long period of time?

Comment: this is my first time using json and PHP so i tried json_decode, but i couldnt figure out how to dig into the array and put it into a variable

Comment: I just made an edit, I have a php facebook api request that returns the json array

Comment: Are you sure that `$facebook->api` is returning JSON and that it's not decoding it for you already?  What does `var_dump($coverphotos)` show?  How about `$coverphotos->data->url`?

Comment: var dump shows this: array(1) { ["id"]=> string(49) "http://graph.facebook.com/160759953968326/picture" }

Answer (score 1):

From the `$coverphotos` variable, you can store the URL of the picture with:

```
$picture = $coverphoto['id'];
```

Comment: I just made an edit, I have a php facebook api request that returns the json array